# Regex for matching Unicode pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate a file's content when is uploaded and I am stuck at the Unicode encoding. I am not interested to find Unicode special characters, that are not in the ASCII range. I am trying to find if the content of the file contains at least one Unicode pattern, like \u0046 for example.

For example, I exclude any file that contains the 'script' word, but what if the file contains this word written in Unicode? Sure, Java decodes it into a normal string when it reads the content, but what if I can't rely on this?

So, as far as I have searched on the Internet, I've seen Unicode characters written like \u0046, or like U+0046. Based on this, I have written the following regex:

```
(\\u|U\+)....
```

This means, \u or U+ followed by four characters. This pattern accomplishes what I desire, but I wonder if there are any other ways to write a Unicode character. It is always \u or U+? Can it be more or less than 4 characters after \u or U+?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. There are for example also XML character escapes like `&#160;` and countless other ways to escape characters.

Comment: I have to search for Unicode characters in a string, but not for what the Unicode code means. For example, U+0061 is the "a" letter, but I don't want to match the letter itself, but the appearance of the Unicode sequence (code). So, if any sequence like U+0061 or \u0061 appears in the file's content, I have to block the file. So I want to find out if I can create a pattern for this.

Comment: Go back a step. What is dangerous depends very much on the type of file (i.e. how it is used later on) than on the actual content. For example U+0046 is harmless in most contexts. Therefore, it is interesting what you want to achieve with this validation. Which files do you check, ...

Comment: I have made several other validations for the file's content. I have patterns to find bad uses of url, import, src, script, javascript and so on. The file's content is saved and after that renamed and loaded into our application like a custom css. My client asked me to not support Unicode at all, so I am trying to find a solution for this. I see that when I read the content, Java decodes a sequence of Unicode characters and probably, if it's a bad word it wont pass the other validations, but I still have to exclude Unicode :)

Comment: I am still not convinced that this is an effective approach, but keeping this warning in mind, your pattern is fine with the exception that U+ can be followed by more than 4 digits, e.g. U+10FFFF

Comment: Ok. I'll leave it like this for now and I will keep in mind your advice. Thanks for your help, Henry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation U+*Any-number-of-hex-digits* belongs to Unicode will not be functional anywhere in code. In java source code and *.properties `\u` followed by four hex digits is a UTF-16 encoding of Unicode, automatically parsed.

The pattern to search for that:

```
"\\\\u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}"
```

Or a String.contains on:

```
"\\u"
```

In other languages than Java `\Uxxxxxx` (six hex chars) is possible, for the full UTF-32 range. Unfortunately upto Java 8 not so.

Comment: how to write a regex for matching a pattern like this \ude08yo ? 'yo' is word concatenated to the unicode '\ude08' ,i need to a way to separate them ,any idea ?

Comment: @AmeenMaheen I thought \uDE08 is a low-surrogate char of a surrogate pair of chars constituting a high Unicode code point. (I might err.) The following high surrogate char's two bytes would never be encoded (by UTF-16) to two ASCII bytes "yo" - so I cannot help there.

Comment: Now i solved the issue ,Used a class from java library called StringEscapeUtils to escape the texts now its not a problem