# Check a string contains at least one Unicode letter using regex

Tags: java, regex

I want such a validation that My String must be contains at least one Unicode letter. The character that will evaluate Character.isLetter() to true.

for example i want

```
~!@#$%^&*(()_+<>?:"{}|\][;'./-=` : false
~~1_~ : true
~~k_~ : true
~~汉_~ : true
```

I know i can use for-loop with Character.isLetter(), but i just don't want to do it.

And This is totally different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278170/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-at-least-one-alphabet-in-java) since it only checks for the English alphabets, but in my case is about one unicode letter. It's not a same at all.

Comment: How does this ```~~汉_~ : true``` evaluate to true? Your 'letter' is multi language? Not just English alphabets?

Comment: Not alphabet but Unicode letter. Try Character.isLetter('汉'). It will return true. And that is what i want.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193200/how-can-i-check-whether-a-byte-array-contains-a-unicode-string-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889924/regex-for-matching-unicode-pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this regex `"\\p{L}|[0-9]"`

To better understand Unicode in Regex read [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Usage code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
        String line = "~!@#$%^&*(()_+<>?:\"{}|\\][;'./-=`";
        String pattern = "\\p{L}|[0-9]"; // regex needed

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        System.out.print("String \"" + line + "\" results to ");
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("TRUE -> Found value: " + m.group(0));
        } else {
            System.out.println("FALSE");
        }
        line = "~~1_~";
        m = r.matcher(line);
        System.out.print("String \"" + line + "\" results to ");
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("TRUE -> Found value: " + m.group(0));
        } else {
            System.out.println("FALSE");
        }
        line = "~~k_~";
        m = r.matcher(line);
        System.out.print("String \"" + line + "\" results to ");
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("TRUE -> Found value: " + m.group(0));
        } else {
            System.out.println("FALSE");
        }
        line = "~~汉_~";
        m = r.matcher(line);
        System.out.print("String \"" + line + "\" results to ");
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("TRUE -> Found value: " + m.group(0));
        } else {
            System.out.println("FALSE");
        }
    }

}
```

Result:

```
String "~!@#$%^&*(()_+<>?:"{}|\][;'./-=`" results to FALSE
String "~~1_~" results to TRUE  
String "~~k_~" results to TRUE -> Found value: k
String "~~汉_~" results to TRUE -> Found value: 汉
```

Comment: I want "number" also return true, so I complete it with "\\p{L}|[0-9]". Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JudeKIM I have edited it so that you can mark it as the correct answer.